# Help with script to zip and purge existing file

Tags: shell-script, find

I am using the commands below to compress and truncate files. I need help to combine this into one command.

```
find *scan*.log -type f -size +1G |xargs -L1 -I file zip file.zip file  
find *scan*.log -type f -size +1G |xargs  -L1 -I file truncate -s 5000 file
```

Comment: Store the result of `find` in a variable, then pass that variable to both `xargs` calls

Comment: 1. you don't need `-L 1 -I file` or `file` at the end of the `xargs` command, all you need is `-n 1` 2. Why are you even using `find` and `xargs` if you already know the filename (`scan.log`)? You don't need either. 3.  the normal process for rotating a log file is a) rename it, b) tell whichever daemon is logging to it to reopen its log file, e.g. by sending it a HUP signal and then c) compress the old log file with gzip or xz or whatever. or just delete it.

Answer (score 1):

The generic method for doing multiple things with each file found by find is something like:

```
find . -name '*scan*.log' -type f -size +1G -exec sh -c \
  'for f in "$@"; do XXX "$f" ; YYY "$f" ; ZZZ "$f" ; done' \
  sh {} +
```

This will run programs XXX, YYY, and ZZZ once for each filename passed into sh by find, passing the same filename to each command in turn.

To rotate a log file, you probably want something like:

```
find . -name '*scan*.log' -type f -size +1G -exec sh -c \
  'for f in "$@"; do
     mv "$f" "$f.old"
     pkill -1 <processname>
     gzip -9 "$f.old"
   done' sh {} +
```

where `<processname>` is the name of the process that writes to the log file.  For this to work, it needs to have been written to close and re-open its log file on a HUP signal. Otherwise use whatever method is appropriate for that program (including killing and restarting the process).

or, better yet, install the `logrotate` package and use that.

Comment: Note that you're changing the OP's command there. The OP is searching for all files in directories named `*scan*.log` as well as any files named `*scan.log*` in the current directory, while you are looking only for files _named_ `*scan*.log`. Granted, this is probably what the OP meant to be be doing, but since it isn't what they are actually doing, you might want to point that out.

Comment: @terdon yeah, i know. i put it down to the OP not knowing how to use find properly, so fixed it.   and it's probably the least of what's wrong with what they're trying to do / how they're trying to do it.  this is just a step back in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks Mate. the first suggestion worked good. That was quick thanks